# jQuery: toogle--> open only one and collapse other sibling items

Tags: javascript, jquery

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDs2/1/
Hi Im trying to accomplish collopsing other parent items while opening only one with jQuery toggle.

I tried

```
var index = $(this).index();
$('.togglebox').eq(index).slideToggle("fast").siblings('.togglebox').hide();
```

I would like you guys help..
Thanks

Comment: So if `item1` is open and `item2` is clicked, you want `item1` to close and `item2` to open?

Comment: yes that's what I want,, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

I changed the javascript to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDs2/8/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide the tooglebox when page load
    var current, toggleBoxes = $(".togglebox").hide();
    //slide up and down when click over heading 2
    $("h3").click(function(){
        current = $(this).next(".togglebox");
        toggleBoxes.not(current).slideUp('fast');
        current.slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

I simply save all the elements with the "togglebox" class and collapse them before doing the slideToggle animation.

Comment: dude, that's almost identical to mine O_O but you beat me by 1 sec posting :P

Answer (score 1):

you weren't calling the hide function in the click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDs2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".togglebox").hide();

    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(".togglebox").slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next(".togglebox").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```